# how to create ec2 instance dynamically using terraform script (with out hardcoding the AMI ID)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

can any one please help, how do i create ec2 instance dynamically (without hardcoding the AMI ID) using terraform.
I have tried using dynamic tag but didn't worked and i searched in many but didn't get the solution.

Comment: "I have tried using dynamic tag but didn't worked" - can you please demonstrate code that you tried and explain why exactly it did not work?

Answer (score 0):

[use ssm for getting the ami id](https://awsfeed.com/uncategorized/using-system-manager-parameter-as-an-alias-for-ami-id)

```
 aws ssm put-parameter --name "web-server" --value "ami-1234abcd" --type "String" --datatype "aws:ec2:image"
```